# How to format x-axis for multiple plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently generating three different figures and I'm having trouble trying to set the format for the x-axis for all three plots. This is what I have currently.

```py
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    plt.figure(1)
    formatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
    plt.plot_date(dates1, y1)
    plt.show()

    plt.figure(2)
    formatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
    plt.plot_date(dates2, y2)
    plt.show()

    plt.figure(3)
    formatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
    plt.plot_date(dates3, y3)
    plt.show()
```

The first figure is formatted as desired but the second and third figure can't seem to detect the x-axis formatting specified. What is the correct way of doing this and is there a way to set the formatting for all three graphs at once?

Comment: How is `ax` defined? Shouldn't you reevaluate it for each figure?

Comment: Yes! I used `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` to reevaluate `ax` for each plot. Do you know if there is a way to set the axes all at once for all the plots?

Comment: I don't think you can do it. I recommend to simply wrap `subplots` + `set_major_formatter` + `set_tick_params`  to simple function returning `fig, ax`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plt.close() to discard plot instances. Or assign each to it's own variable.

```
    plt.figure(1)
    formatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
    plt.plot_date(dates1, y1)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()


    plt.figure(2)
    formatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
    plt.plot_date(dates2, y2)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

    plt.figure(3)
    formatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30)
    plt.plot_date(dates3, y3)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work. However, reevaluating `ax` for every plot worked!